# Trying to run script on terminal that includes code to open a browser and search

Tags: python

I made a file with python to open the browser and search on google. When I go into my 'Python' directory and run the file it works just fine. I copied that file to my home directory and used the `chmod 755` so that I can execute using `./filename` but when I execute it does nothing, no errors occur though.

So why does the file not execute and bring up the browser when I use `./filename` vs running the file in its home directory with `python filename.py`?

I am also getting this error now when trying to execute with ./filename format

./google.py: line 1: import: command not found
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium
./google.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./google.py: line 4:`search1 = ' '.join(sys.argv)[9:]'
Code here:

```
'''
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
search1 = ' '.join(sys.argv)[9:]
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/users/roughcaster/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.maximize_window()
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
search.click()
search.send_keys(search1)
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]')
submit.click()
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run script as `./filename` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is used to detect what application should execute this script. Try to add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of the script

Comment: from: can't read /var/mail/selenium
./google.py: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./google.py: line 4: `search1 = ' '.join(sys.argv)[9:]'

Comment: This is the error that is coming up now but i havent changed the code from when it worked in the python directory

Comment: @Roughcaster Is your script long? If no, can you add it's content in your post? Else show at least first lines

Comment: @Roughcaster There should be three backticks before the first line of code and three backticks after

Comment: @Roughcaster Sorry, have no ideas, what can be wrong